# Why is excitation potential taken in $\rm eV$ when $\rm eV$ is actually the unit of energy and not potential difference? Shouldn’t it be Volt?

Tags: potential, potential-energy, terminology, units

The unit of excitation potential should be Volt and not $\rm eV$. My book says it’s $\rm eV$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is something which we always do in Physics, we interchangeably use the words “potential” and “potential energy”.
Whether a quantity is really a potential or a potential energy is something we determine after looking at the units.

Answer (score 1):

When we say there are two points with a potential difference of one volt we mean that the work done to transport a unit charge from one point to the other is one joule. So a volt is a potential energy per unit charge.

If we have a charge $q$ instead of one coulomb then the work done when we transport the charge across our one volt potential difference is $q$ joules, and if we take our charge to the charge of a single electron $e$ then the work done is $e$ joules i.e. $1.602 \times 10^{-19}$ joules.

So we can define an *electron volt* or *eV* as this quantity of energy. The reason for doing this is that the electron volt turns out to be very convenient when describing the excited states of atoms and molecules. As a general rule the energies are a few electron volts so they are easy to remember. For example the ionisation energy of a hydrogen atom is $13.6$ eV.

The point of all this is the the volt and the electron volt may be different but they are closely related.